# How to move Joomla mySQL DB to Maria DB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, joomla3.0

My web provider just informed me that they will dump MySQL and will replace that with MariaDB (due to the reason that they will soon move over to Debian9 and Debian 9 will no longer include MySQL and will include MariaSQL (see [here](http://mysqlrelease.com/2017/06/debian-9-and-mysql-watch-out/)). They said they will move over my files, however I need to move my DB content from server1 to server2 manually as I need to adjust the joomla configuration.php to fit that.

I learned now that there should be no real difference in using MySQL or MariaDB so I think its fine to move my content. However I have issues to do that. I know I must adjust my configuration.php to point to the new server, however I do not know how I can export my the MySQL joomla content and import that in Maria DB. In the very past I used a cgi-script to dump the SQL content to a file and then use another cgi-script to upload that to a new DB. However that's 10 years ago and I´m not sure if that would be still the best option here.

thanks

Comment: It's possible your hosting provider will migrate your MySQL data for you. Ask whether they will.  If not, get a joomla extension to backup and restore your database.  This one might do it. https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/backup-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this generally depends on your hosting configuration, mainly on where they allow access to your database from, but normally, it is as easy as an export and an import like:

```
mysqldump olddatabasename -h oldhostname -u oldusername -p > mysqldata.sql
```

and then

```
mysql -D newdatabasename -h newhostname -u newusername -p < mysqldata.sql
```

Obviously you will need to adjust your PHP settings to point to new host.